# Custom XML Serialization and handling CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, cdata, serialization

I have a custom XML Serializer as follows

```
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), true).Count() == 0)
            {
                var attrList = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute), true);

                if (attrList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    XmlElementAttribute xe = (XmlElementAttribute)attrList[0];
                    writer.WriteStartElement(xe.ElementName);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(pi.Name);
                }

                if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(int) || (pi.PropertyType == typeof(float)))
                {
                    writer.WriteString(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
                }
                else if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    DateTime dt = (DateTime)(pi.GetValue(this, null));

                    writer.WriteString(dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"));
                }
                else
                {

                    if (pi.GetValue(this, null) == null) writer.WriteString(String.Empty);
                    else
                    {
                        // write code to generate CDATA 

                        String val = pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString();

                        if (val.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1)
                            writer.WriteString(String.Format(@"<![CDATA[{0}]]>", pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString()));
                        else writer.WriteString(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
                    }

                }

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem arises when the value contains one of the characters which is invalid in an XML Value. This is detected successfully with these lines

```
                    if (val.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1)
                        writer.WriteString(String.Format(@"<![CDATA[{0}]]>", pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString()));
                    else writer.WriteString(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
```

The problem is the creation of the CDATA - instead of getting a properly formatted CDATA what I am getting is & gt ; and & lt ;

So how should you create a properly formatted CDATA within a custom serializer?

Comment: If you want to write markup directly, use `WriteRaw` rather than `WriteString`. (Note that I have no idea, in the broader context, if writing CDATA this way is the best approach -- I mean, there's also `WriteCData`, after all.)

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Jeroen Mostert in the comments.

Replace the following code

```
if (val.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1) writer.WriteString(String.Format(@"<![CDATA[{0}]]>", pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString()));
else writer.WriteString(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
```

with

```
if (val.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1) writer.WriteRaw(String.Format(@"<![CDATA[{0}]]>", pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString()));
else writer.WriteString(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
```

The CDATA is then written to the stream correctly and saved to disk in the correct format.

WriteString has been replaced with WriteRaw.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `writer.WriteCData(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString())` work as well? It ought to, and would be simpler. Also, technically, your output would not be wrong if *everything* was written as CDATA, so you could omit the check -- but it might be larger than necessary.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert to be honest I'm not sure. I'm dealing with medical records so went with your original answer as I need to get it working very quickly. For the same reason I wanted to reduce the number of changes made to the data during processing. The problems occur because the source of the data produces less strict XML than the application which reads the data.